# PowerBI Filter or Sum based on Calendar Slicers

Tags: powerbi, dax

We run a hotel business.  The structure of my fact table is arranged as a P&L report.  Every month has a row for specific line items.

There's Month/QTD/YTD/L12M period slicers.

I've added columns for the total number of rooms sold and travelers per month in order to use them as references for writing Measures.  This number stays constant throughout the month.

I want to build unit analytics into the dashboard.  For example, the cost of linens per traveler per month. If I choose QTD, I want to add up the linen cost this quarter and divide by # of travelers this quarter.

To do this, I first created a Travelers Measure to start.  The issue I'm running into is how to make it react to the period slicers.

If I try to use:

`Travelers = SUM` it adds up all the travelers or rooms sold even if it's within the same month (ie. in January - if I have 10 line items for the report and there were 10 total travelers, then it would show 100 travelers)

`Travelers = MIN` displays the correct number based on the selected month slicer, but fails to SUM the travelers based on the period slicer chosen.  (eg. if I had 30 travelers QTD, it would still only show the number from the chosen month).

I'm no longer sure whether this is a DAX issue or if I should arrange my data differently.
Thank you!
Link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5wl4dc5f560cswv/TestReport.pbix?dl=0

Comment: I've opened the provided PBIX file and I'm affraid I don't see exactly what you are trying to achieve. I don't see any "Customer" in columns names or table. Can you provide more explanation on what you are trying to achieve, the expected result, etc ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @JérémieL ah so sorry we had changed the labels to "Rooms Sold" and "Travelers".  I've updated the Question

Comment: For the sum of travelers. For example, for January the expected result would be 701 or 51*701 = 35751 ?
Because in `Actual`, there are 51 lines for January with 701 travelers ?

Comment: Say for example we are in March, we want it to output 701 if we select January, but 701 + 771 (February) if we select QTD.